# How to enable NVIDIA cuQuantum QPU access in qBraid?

Tags: quantum-computing, qbraid

I'm currently using the default Jupyter instances for qBraid, and looking to try some jobs on a GPU. I see that qBraid has access to a configured GPU rig, and offers this as a service, but it's not clear how to access this.

What is the process for moving my job into the qBraid GPU?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At time of writing there's a pre-launch waiting list for the Lab GPU server (see the [official docs](https://docs.qbraid.com/projects/lab/en/latest/lab/gpu.html) for more on that). The specs look promising.

- Provider - NVIDIA
- GPU Architecture - Volta
- GPU Name - Telsa V100
- CUDA - 12.0
- Driver - 25.105.17